# Setting up a batch script to run powershell with arguments

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have  a PowerShell script that takes an argument/command and executes well in PowerShell. I am looking at setting up a batch script to run following commands as is to mimic PowerShell

(-config is a function that's defined within script)

```
C\temp\power_t1.ps1 -config d:\temp\dirlist.txt
```

I wrote a batch script something like

```
ECHO OFF
POWERSHELL.EXE -file "C\temp\power_t1.ps1 -config d:\temp\dirlist.txt"
```

but this doesn't seem to be working.

Any suggestions?

Regards,
Ruben

Answer (score 0):

The script file and the arguments for the script file are separate arguments for `powershell.exe`.  If you look at `powershell.exe /?`, under `-File`, you see:

> File must be the last parameter in the command, because all characters typed after the File parameter name are interpreted as the script file path followed by the script parameters.

Try:

```
POWERSHELL.EXE -File "C\temp\power_t1.ps1" -config d:\temp\dirlist.txt
```

Basically, treat everything after the `-File` parameter more or less as though you were writing it in PowerShell with the call operator (`&`).

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for the quick response, I tried that option as well but didn't work for me.

if I am using Powershell I will simpley do this....

[ c:\Temp\power_t1.ps1 -config d:\temp\dirlist.tst]

and that executes the script. I am trying to setup a batch script that initiates powershell command and run the entire command